# Date format in file open menus in Ubuntu applications

Tags: date

Whenever I am opening a file in Ubuntu applications, be it LibreOffice or Document Viewer, the date format always appears in the mm/dd/yyyy format in the file open (and save) menus. Please see these images,

[image: Libre Office File Open Menu]

[image: Document Viewer File Open Menu]

From the consistency among applications, I presume that this is something OS specific rather than being application specific.

I tried looking under System Settings, without any avail.

Could you please tell me how do I set the date to dd/mm/yyyy (or any other format of my choice) in the file menus?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I found it. Mistakenly, I was looking under the date related ones.

I need to change this in System Setting->Language Support.

[image]

From this go to tab Regional Formats and choose your preferred format. Click on Apply System Wide.

[image]

Please remember that one needs to logout and then login for the changes to take effect.